# GA4 explortion can't see percentage of total

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am making an exploration on GA4 but on top of my table I cannot see anymore the percentage of total which I remember was a measure I used to have. Is it possibile I accidentally removed it without knowing?
How can I restore it?
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwxY.png)

I haven't tried anything because I thought it was an intrinsic property of GA4

Answer (score 0):

Is is that you intend to see the percentage of total by months? In that case you have to make the month dimension as Columns instead of Rows, then percentage will be displayed.

I have no idea why GA4 won't show percentage information of row dimension.